# Answering on closed question

Tags: bug, ios-app

I wanted to report a small UI bug on the iOS app.

Yesterday I was answering a question ([there](https://serverfault.com/questions/872951/should-i-migrate-2008-dc-to-new-2012-dc-or-simply-make-a-new-domain-very-small)) in the iOS app, and in the meantime I was typing my answer the question got closed by a user.

I didn't receive the usual warning you have on the web version while you type and the question got closed, and I was able to submit my answer. I found it was already closed after I clicked <kbd>Submit</kbd>, as the iOS app shows you the question after.

I double checked today with another question, and if the question is already closed the iOS app does not offer me the option to add an answer (and my mobile browser does not allow me either).

Is it a wanted behavior from the iOS app?

- App version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 5s (GSM)
- OS version: Version 10.3.2 (build 14F89)

Comment: "Is it a wanted behavior from the ios-app?" - You indicated that you are unable to submit an answer to a closed question with the iOS application that is indeed intended behavior.

Comment: @Catija it is on purpose, set by Jeff in ancient times. There is four hours "grace period" which let answers be submitted to closed questions.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I had find the info for the delay, but I didnt used to find the dupe you found, as yes its the same. I would mark catija's dupe on the other hand, as the answer there clearly state it's by design.